# How to get piece of text from source code of HTML page?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a link of some search facebook page which contains link for only one user
https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=a_mudr%40mail.ru&type=users&init=s%3Aemail&nomc=0

Then I am getting its source code
view-source:https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=example%40post.com&type=users&init=s%3Aemail&nomc=0

How can I get user ID from there?
As you can notice it is there as href="https://www.facebook.com/amudrevskyi"

I am working with JavaScript to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you want to retrieve the userId, and you know that the url you are working with is in the correct structure, you can use the following code:

```
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/amudrevskyi';
var userId = url.split('//')[1].split('/')[1];
console.log(userId);
```